# Bold when writing in another language in vaadin 8

Tags: fonts, grid, vaadin, vaadin8

I use `vaadin 8.9.3` and I ran into a problem: when a column with a Russian name is added to the table, the font in it is displayed bolder than the column with an English name. Looks like a problem with fonts. The images below show examples (Google Chrome):

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

This is very annoying. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your primary CSS font does not support the Cyrillic alphabet, so it uses another fallback font for those characters.

[MDN says this about font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)

> font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an available font does not have a glyph for a needed character, the latter fonts are tried.

What you need to do is to modify the `font-family` to use a primary font that support Cyrillic characters, or then you need to change either the primary or one of the fallback fonts to something that looks more similar.

[Here's some info](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-valo.html) on theming and setting font-family with Valo.